# How to support retries in AWSCognitoIdentityCustomAuthentication

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS User Pools on iOS.

The interface `AWSCognitoIdentityCustomAuthentication` has two key functions:

```
func getCustomChallengeDetails(_ authenticationInput: AWSCognitoIdentityCustomAuthenticationInput, customAuthCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityCustomChallengeDetails>)
```

and

```
func didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?)
```

and a call to submit answers. e.g.,

```
self.customAuthenticationCompletion!.set(result: details)
```

I've a 2-step custom authentication: email an access code to the user and then confirm the validity of that access code when entered by the user. All this is working fine when the user correctly enters the access code.

But if they submit an incorrect value, the code correctly handles this, but after `didCompleteStepWithError()` is called a new round is begun and `getCustomChallengeDetails()` is called again and a new access code is emailed.

How can I give my user a second (or third) try at entering an access code before another is sent off?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to enhance the AWS User Pool trigger code to only send out emails when an access code is first generated.

Comment: Could you add details or a link?